# Trigonometric equation with quadrangle

Tags: trigonometry

I need some help solving this. Any hints/ideas?
We got a quadrangle, inscribed in a circle. The two opposite corners are $x$ and $y$. (From this we know $x+y=180^{\circ }$)?

Find $\cos(x)$ if $\tan(y)=-2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\tan y=\tan(\pi-x)=-\tan x=-2 \rightarrow \tan x=2$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Sure, solved it! Thank you much. It's interesting I did the same thing you wrote but couldn't think how to get further in that moment. :)

Comment: You are very welcome. Don't worry, that happens some times!